# Cache Management in Android

Tags: android, caching

I made an Android application in which data fetches from SOAP service .Actually my application  have lots of calling from the server side . And after calling web service i populate the data in listview .There are multiple Category in my application , if i click any category its sub catrgory populates and it bind that sub category into listview . If i click and sub category ,another web service called which will retreive files with respect to sub category . So this is very annoying for me that every time service will call.It cost lots of bandwidth .I read about cache management .Please give some idea about cache mansgement . Can i use  CacheManager class . What should i do ???

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ICS has response caching on HttpUrlConnection these days but I have never used it, you can read about how to enable it in ICS here http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html.

There is also a backport of response caching here https://github.com/candrews/HttpResponseCache

However, rather than binding data directly following a network request, I would put it into a SQLite database and then bind from a cursor. You can check out a Google IO presentation about this here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE that should give you some great ideas on how to do this correctly.

Hope that helps.